# "pip install langchain openai" not install properly showing error

Tags: pip, openai-api, langchain, toml

I'm facing an issue while trying to install the langchain and openai packages using the command pip install langchain openai. The installation process fails with an error related to building wheels for the multidict package. The error indicates a requirement for Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater. I have already installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools as suggested, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this error and successfully install the required packages?

Error Details:

`Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
...
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
`

I've already installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools from this link.
I'm using Python 3.12 on Windows.

I want to install langchain and open package.